# "receive time" or "receipt time"

Tags: word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Let's say a message (e-mail or SMS) was received at a certain point in time.

What phrase is appropriate for this point in time?

> "receive time" or "receipt time" or something else?

---

More info:

I plan to use this phrase as the short label in the graphical user interface of an application and as the variable name (e.g. receive_time) in the program code.

Comment: Would you please provide the example-sentence in which you want to use that phrase?

Comment: Is "timestamp" too technical?

Comment: I plan to use this phrase as the short label in the graphical user interface of application and as the variable name (e.g. receive_time) in the program  code.

Comment: /time received/ is what we would say. Receipt in English is what you get when you buy something. A slip of paper.

Comment: @StephenS "timestamp" is very good word but it's not clear (what event denotes this time?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Time received" is the most natural, or simply "received" followed by the actual time value (similar to how ELL displays the "edited/asked/answered" values)

> received Jan 20 '16 at 14:43
>
> received 2016-01-20 14:43 GMT